# Airflow GCS to BigQuery Cloud Storage Bucket URI not found

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have the following airflow code which (is supposed to ) read in data from a CSV > Google Cloud Storage then to Google Big Query.

I can confirm I've configured the connection details in the admin tab of airflow.

```
with DAG('bigquery_data_load', 
schedule_interval='@hourly', 
catchup=False, 
default_args=default_arguments) as dag:

    load_data = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='load_data',
    bucket='tate-airflow-bucket',
    source_objects=['*'],
    source_format='CSV',
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    field_delimiter=',',
    destination_project_dataset_table='technical-seo-audits.vehicle_analytics.history',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default'
    )
    
    query = """
        SELECT * except (rank)
        FROM (
            SELECT
              *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY vehicle_id ORDER BY DATETIME(date, TIME(hour, minute, 0)) DESC
              ) as rank
            FROM `technical-seo-audits.vehicle_analytics.history`) as latest
        WHERE rank = 1;
    """
```

Here are the log details:

```
*** Reading local file: /home/jordan/airflow/logs/dag_id=bigquery_data_load/run_id=scheduled__2022-08-01T20:00:00+00:00/task_id=load_data/attempt=1.log
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1179} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: bigquery_data_load.load_data scheduled__2022-08-01T20:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1179} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: bigquery_data_load.load_data scheduled__2022-08-01T20:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1376} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1377} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1378} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1397} INFO - Executing <Task(GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator): load_data> on 2022-08-01 20:00:00+00:00
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 107990 to run task
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'bigquery_data_load', 'load_data', 'scheduled__2022-08-01T20:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '19', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/bigquery_data_load.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp9mn347f9', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp1npjp8bl']
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 19: Subtask load_data
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {task_command.py:371} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: bigquery_data_load.load_data scheduled__2022-08-01T20:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host system76-pc.localdomain
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1589} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=Tate Lowry
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=bigquery_data_load
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=load_data
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-08-01T20:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-08-01T20:00:00+00:00
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID 'google_cloud_default' for task execution.
[2022-08-01, 17:08:04 UTC] {bigquery.py:1539} INFO - Inserting job airflow_1659391684482660_4e6c5e9b679be20f2defde03e3dc8c1e
[2022-08-01, 17:08:05 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1909} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jordan/miniconda3/envs/airflow-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery.py", line 279, in execute
    bq_hook.run_load(
  File "/home/jordan/miniconda3/envs/airflow-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py", line 1801, in run_load
    job = self.insert_job(configuration=configuration, project_id=self.project_id)
  File "/home/jordan/miniconda3/envs/airflow-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 457, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jordan/miniconda3/envs/airflow-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py", line 1545, in insert_job
    job.result(timeout=timeout, retry=retry)
  File "/home/jordan/miniconda3/envs/airflow-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 728, in result
    return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jordan/miniconda3/envs/airflow-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 137, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not found: Uris gs://tate-airflow-bucket/*
[2022-08-01, 17:08:05 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1415} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=bigquery_data_load, task_id=load_data, execution_date=20220801T200000, start_date=20220801T210804, end_date=20220801T210805
[2022-08-01, 17:08:05 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 19 for task load_data (404 Not found: Uris gs://tate-airflow-bucket/*; 107990)
[2022-08-01, 17:08:06 UTC] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-08-01, 17:08:06 UTC] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

I've tried:

- removing the wildcard from the source_objects section and leaving it blank
- adding a new bucket
- appending "gs://" to the bucket string

I wasn't able to find any documentation on whether or not airflow supports wild cards in their source_objects parameters.

I should also mention I got a DeprecationWarning: This operator is deprecated. Please use `BigQueryInsertJobOperator. Not sure if this is playing a role or not.

---

Editing this post in case the solution helps other people out:

I replaced the 'GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator' with 'LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator' as I was trying to upload a CSV file from my desktop to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Can you try uploading just a single file? Just use `source_objects=["folder/my-file.csv"]`

Comment: And how is your folder structure inside the bucket? Is every CSV file on the root level? If not maybe try using `source_objects=["**.csv"]`.

Comment: What airflow version are you using?

Comment: I tried your code it was working fine. All my CSV files are located in the root level. I'm using composer version 1.19.4 and airflow 2.2.5.

Comment: Turns out my CSV file was not on the root level.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed by @JordanLowry, the code works fine the only problem was that the CSV files were not located on the root level.

The fix is to move the files over to the root folder for the code to properly work.

But if you want your files in a "folder" structure, the code should be updated to include the prefix of the "folder" in `source_objects` like the code below:

```
source_objects=['folder_1/*.csv', 'folder_2/*.csv', 'folder_3/*.csv']
```

Comment: I appreciate you following up! I'll keep that in mind moving forward.